# Calling Python OpenCV code from MATLAB is not working on Ubuntu

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to call a Python file which uses OpenCV from MATLAB. This is working fine on Windows using the the following;

```
dos('python webcam_test.py');
```

however when I try to run the same python script from MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04, using `dos` or `system`, I'm receiving the following error in MATLAB:

```
File "webcam_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /tmp/B3p0_293380_4550/build-glnxa64.glnxa64.293380.r000/B3p0/glnxa64/OpenCV/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

This is confusing for me since the python works fine on Ubuntu when executed manually from command prompt.

I have also tested basic python code such as printing "hello world" and this works when run from the MATLAB using `system` or `dos` functions. Why am I getting an OpenCV error when run from MATLAB but not when run manually?

Comment: How is the path to the image file defined in `python webcam_test.py`?

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the response. I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your question. My python code is using "cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()" to capture a frame and "cv2.imshow" to display the image. AFAIK there is no image path, the matlab should just execute the bash command which executes the python that captures frames and displays them??